# how to get diff days between two dates if I consider every month is day 30 only

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-08-17')));
$end_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-09-01')));
$diff = $start_date->diffInDays($end_date);
```

Days between these two dates  is **15**, because aug is 31 day but in my case I consider every month is 30 day, so the difference should be **14**

Comment: Obviously you can't use the standard methods, if you redeclare how many days a month has...

Answer (score 0):

Carbon has a `daysInMonth` attribute which returns the number of days for a given date. So you could use that and do something like the following:

```
public function diffInDays($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $diff = $start_date->diffInDays($end_date);

    $daysInMonths = [$start_date->daysInMonth, $end_date->daysInMonth];

    foreach ($daysInMonths as $count) {
        if ($count >= 31) {
            $diff--;
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Then you would use the above as follows:

```
$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-08-17')));
$end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-09-01')));

$diff = $this->diffInDays($start_date, $end_date);
```

This could be improved upon but the principle works as desired. The result is `14`.